# Headache caused by Swift's case-insensitive #import

Tags: xcode, swift, linker-errors, importerror

Last night I was importing Swifter into my project but got missing symbols like these

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__TMdO10SwifterIOS4JSON", referenced from:
      __TMaGVSs10DictionarySSO10SwifterIOS4JSON_ in CWAppDelegate.o
  "__TMaC10SwifterIOS7Swifter", referenced from:
      __TFC9Chatswood13CWAppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb in CWAppDelegate.o
      __TMaGSqC10SwifterIOS7Swifter_ in CWAppDelegate.o
  "__TFC10SwifterIOS7SwifterCfMS0_FT7accountCSo9ACAccount_S0_", referenced from:
      __TFC9Chatswood13CWAppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb in CWAppDelegate.o
  "__TFC10SwifterIOS7Swifter22getUserStreamDelimitedfS0_FTGSqSb_13stallWarningsGSqSb_35includeMessagesFromFollowedAccountsGSqSb_14includeRepliesGSqSb_5trackGSqGSaSS__9locationsGSqGSaSS__18stringifyFriendIDsGSqSb_8progressGSqFT6statusGSqGVSs10DictionarySSOS_4JSON___T__19stallWarningHandlerGSqFT4codeGSqSS_7messageGSqSS_11percentFullGSqSi__T__7failureGSqFT5errorCSo7NSError_T___CS_18SwifterHTTPRequest", referenced from:
      __TFC9Chatswood13CWAppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb in CWAppDelegate.o
```

Comment: @user1415571 i have solved already, posted as Q&A

Answer (score 0):

At last I found it was caused by accidentally writing `#import SwifteriOS` into `#import SwifterIOS`. I was wondering if this should be reported with the compiler (preprocessor for older languages) rather than the linker, whose report is just not clear and informative for users to track the origin of problems. I think the Xcode has mixed many responsibilities of compiler, linker and even (the crashy) SourceKitService coding assistant, although most of the intentions and results are positive.

Further hints and discussion welcomed :)